# Как работает scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

У меня есть список из примерно 1000 элементов. Каждый элемент содержит две координаты `x` и `y`, обе от 0 до 200. Мне необходимо разбить все точки на 25 секторов, каждый из которых имеет длину 40 на 40. То есть у меня большой квадрат 200 на 200 с 1000 точками, мне надо разбить его на 5 интервалов по каждому направлению и подсчитать сколько попало точек в каждый интервал. Сейчас я вручную иду по исходным данным, определяю номер ячейки и увеличиваю для нее счетчик, но как я понял это можно сделать с помощью функции `binned_statistic_2d` из модуля `scipy.stats`. Никак не могу понять, как ее правильно использовать.

Comment: Выглядит как задание из "Построение выводов по данным" курса на coursera.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример для массива, состоящего из 10 точек:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic_2d

a = np.array(
[[3, 9],
 [1, 3],
 [10, 10],
 [0, 3],
 [4, 7],
 [2, 2],
 [9, 4],
 [7, 0],
 [4, 5],
 [0, 1]])

xbins = [0, 5, 10]
ybins = [0, 5, 10]
ret = binned_statistic_2d(a[:,0],a[:,1],None,'count',bins=[xbins, ybins])
```

результат:

```
print(ret.statistic)
#[[4. 3.]
# [2. 1.]]
print(ret.x_edge)
#[ 0.  5. 10.]
print(ret.y_edge)
#[ 0.  5. 10.]
```

на графике видно что в нижний-левый квадрант попадает `4` точки, в нижний-правый - `2`, в верхний-левый - `3`, в верхний-правый - `1`:

```
plt.scatter(a[:, 0], a[:,1], s=100, c='orange')
plt.axvline(5, color='r')
plt.axhline(5, color='b')
plt.xlim(-1, 11)
plt.ylim(-1, 11)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS все интервалы, задающие границы секторов ("bins edges"), кроме последних (по каждой оси) - полуоткрытые. В нашем случае интервалы по `X` и по `Y` одинаковые

```
[0, 5), [5, 10]
#             ^
#             |___ последний интервал включает и правую границу
```

Таким образом точка `(4,5)` принадлежит верхнему-левому квадранту, а `(10,10)` - верхнему-правому

---

В вашем случае границы секторов можно задать так:

```
xbins = np.arange(0, 240, 40)
ybins = np.arange(0, 240, 40)
```

---

```
In [9]: xbins
Out[9]: array([  0,  40,  80, 120, 160, 200])

In [10]: ybins
Out[10]: array([  0,  40,  80, 120, 160, 200])
```

PS еще проще задать число корзин/секторов целым числом - если все сектора одинакового размера:

```
ret = binned_statistic_2d(a[:,0],a[:,1],None,'count',bins=5)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не могли бы вы пояснить общую идею позади этой функции? Она позволяет измерить много статистики. Уверен, многим людям будет очень полезна эта информация, потому что в исходном коде не все очевидно и не так просто разобраться.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, оформил в виде отдельного ответа, чтобы не перегружать этот ответ...

Comment: Большое спасибо! Уже изучаю :)

Comment: Спасибо и вам за интересный вопрос! Я раньше не сталкивался с этими функциями, поэтому мне самому стало интересно разобраться как они работают ;)

Comment: `bins` можно не вычислять в виде массивов, а передать как целое (для случая в вопросе: `bins=5`.

Comment: @jfs, да, для корзин/интервалов одинакового размера, как в вопросе, проще указать число корзин.

Answer (score 1):

Отвечая на вопрос ["Как работает scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/907606) возникло много сопутствующих вопросов.

Для того чтобы понять как работает эта 2D функция, проще сначала разобраться как работает и что делает её 1D аналог - [scipy.stats.binned_statistic()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html)

---

[**binned_statistic(x, values, statistic='mean', bins=10, range=None)**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html) предназначена для вычисления различных статистических характеристик (функций) для массива элементов `values`. Причем все элементы сначала "раскладываются" по корзинам / интервалам и уже потом статистика считается для каждой корзины отдельно.
Для "раскладывания" данных по корзинам используются параметры `x`, `bins` и `range`:

- параметр `x` задаёт вектор / список элементов, по значениям которых будут раскладываться элементы по корзинам
- параметр `values` задаёт вектор / список данных, по которым расчитывается статистика. Размерность `values` должна совпадать с размерностью `x`
- параметр `statistic` задаёт статистическую функцию: `min`, `max`, `mean`, `median`, `sum`, `count`, `user-defined function`
- параметр `bins` - задаёт границы интервалов / корзин и может быть задан:

  - как целое число - число корзин. Все корзины/интервалы будут равной длины.
  - как массив границ интервалов. Пример: `bins=[0,3,10,50]` будет транслирован в следующие интервалы: `[0,3),  [3,10), [10,50]`. Все интервалы кроме последнего полуоткрытые (не включают правую границу). Последний интервал включает и правую границу.
- параметр `range` - задаёт минимальное и максимальное значение, которые будут использоваться для раскладывания элементов по корзинам. Все значения вне данного диапазона будут проигнорированы. По умолчанию будут использоваться значения `(x.min(), x.max())`

Примеры:

```
from scipy import stats

x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 5, 7])
values = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 3.0])
bins=2
r = stats.binned_statistic(x, values, 'sum', bins=bins)
print(f'stats: {r.statistic}, bin_edges: {r.bin_edges}, bin_numbers: {r.binnumber}')
```

вывод:

```
stats: [4.  4.5], bin_edges: [1. 4. 7.], bin_numbers: [1 1 1 2 2]
```

функция расчитала границы интервалов следующим образом:

```
b_edges = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), bins+1)
print(b_edges)
#[1. 4. 7.]
```

Первые три элемента из `x` попали в первую корзину, последние два во вторую. При расчете статистики используются элементы из `values` с индексами соответствующих элементов из `x`.

Таким образом сумма первых трех элементов из `values` - `4.0` (первая корзина), а последних двух - `4.5` (вторая корзина).

Если поменять первый элемент в `x`: `1` --> `100`:

```
x = np.array([100, 1, 2, 5, 7])
```

и повторить тот же расчет:

```
r = stats.binned_statistic(x, values, 'sum', bins=bins)
print(f'stats: {r.statistic}, bin_edges: {r.bin_edges}, bin_numbers: {r.binnumber}')
```

получим

```
stats: [7.5 1. ], bin_edges: [  1.   50.5 100. ], bin_numbers: [2 1 1 1 1]
```

т.к. поменялись интервалы: `[1.0,50.5), [50.5,100.0]`, соответственно все элементы из `x` кроме `100` попадут в первую корзину, `100` - во вторую.
При расчете статистики используются элементы из `values` с индексами, соответствующими элементам из `x`. Т.е. в первую корзину попадает сумма всех элементов из `values`, кроме первого (`1.+2.+1.5+3.`), а во вторую только первый элемент - `1.`

```
In [91]: values[1:].sum()
Out[91]: 7.5

In [92]: values[:1].sum()
Out[92]: 1.0
```

---

Пример с интервалами заданными в виде массива границ интервалов и элементами `x`, "выпадающими" за границы интервалов (`-10`, `10`):

```
x = np.array([10, -10, 2, 5, 7])
values = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 3.0])
bins = [0, 3, 5, 7]  # [0,3), [3,5), [5,7]
r = stats.binned_statistic(x, values, 'sum', bins=bins)
print(f'stats: {r.statistic}, bin_edges: {r.bin_edges}, bin_numbers: {r.binnumber}')
```

вывод:

```
stats: [2.  0.  4.5], bin_edges: [0. 3. 5. 7.], bin_numbers: [4 0 1 3 3]
```

пояснения:

```
  x values Номер корзины интервал              комментарий
--- ------ ------------- -------- ------------------------
-10    1.0             4      ??? не попадает в статистику
 10    1.0             0      ??? не попадает в статистику
  2    2.0             1    [0,3)
  5    1.5             3    [5,7]
  7    3.0             3    [5,7]
```